# NotFound page rendering above all components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I've had a problem with rendering `NotFound` page with the following code, component `Routing` is a children in my `Switch` component located in App.tsx:

```
const Routing = (): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <>
      {publicRouting.map(({ path, component }, i) => (
        <Route key={i} path={path} component={component} />
      ))}
      {isAuthenticated() && (
        <Main>
          {routing.map(({ path, component }, i) => (
            <Route exact key={i} path={path} component={component} />
          ))}
        </Main>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

my publicRouting and routes used above:

```
export const publicRoutes = {
  login: "/login",
  notFound: "*"
};

export const publicRouting = [
  { path: publicRoutes.login, component: Login },
  { path: publicRoutes.notFound, component: NotFound }
];
```

can someone tell me why, after logging in to private routes `(isAuthenticated() === true)` my `NotFound` page is always rendering above the `Main` component?

Here is the small screenshot of this situation, NotFound component is physically rendering above the Main component and his children
[image]

If anyone want more code then it feel free, I will paste it

thanks for any help!

Comment: putting exact on the public routing map should fix it. `{publicRouting.map(({ path, component }, i) => (
        <Route exact key={i} path={path} component={component} />
      ))}`

Comment: @Adarsh not helping :/

Comment: also the notFound route should be "/*" instead of "*". if that doesn't work you can do the empty route '' but then you have to add the notFound route manually without the exact at the bottom

Comment: @Adarsh can you show the second approach?

Comment: adding slash before * not working :/

Comment: `<Route path="" component={NotFound} /> // empty ""
<Route path="/*" component={NotFound} /> // star /*
<Route component={NotFound} /> // without path`

these are three ways of doing it and all of them have worked for me in the past. make sure that the notFound route is declared at the end, so no routes after it